# QueryTestablePermissions response doesn't include "AcessContextManager.*" permissions

Tags: permissions, google-iam

Based on this documentation : https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/custom-roles-permissions-support

There are several permissions with prefix : `AccessContextManager`. But After I ran the API : QueryTestablePermission, it doesn't include those list.
Also when I create new IAM Role with permission:`AccessContextManager.*` (let's say it's : `accesscontextmanager.accessLevels.create`), it will return exception which said `accesscontextmanager.accessLevels.create` is not a valid permission.

Anyone know what have I been missed on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `accesscontextmanager.*` and some others permissions are applicable on **Organization leve**l, while my code was on project level. So it's the correct behavior.